# Couldn't open exe.file released by visual studio 2015

Tags: windows-7, visual-studio-2015, windows-10

I had release built an application with visual studio 2015 in windows 10, I copy the exe file to a windows 7 pc, and the program couldn't run, the framework version is already the latest version. I can't figure out what the problem is, hope anyone can help in solving this problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the problem/error message?

Comment: @AlexBelotserkovskiy when I double click it loading icon is changed, but it just doesn't show and appear anything.

Comment: Is it UWP app, WPF, Win Forms, etc.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try in a Compability Mode? 
Rightclick the .exe and Troubleshoot compability.